# Regular expression for inserting span tags

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string

I need a regular expression for the replacement of a string into below wrapper format.

Example input:

```
C# Regular expression for combination of space, alpha and special-character. Also for delta
```

Output:

```
<span>C# <span>Regular <span>expression <span>for <span>combination <span>of </span><span>space<span>,</span> </span><span>alpha </span><span>and </span><span>special</span><span>-</span><span>character</span>. </span><span>Also </span><span>for </span><span>delta</span>
```

Comment: Where are your attempts? What doesn't work?

Comment: Why do you want the `#` to stay together with the preceding `C`, but not the comma with the preceding `e`? What is the logic behind this? NB: Your `span` tags are not all closing...

Comment: Why do some words get proper HTML and others get invalid HTML? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this `replace` call:

```js
var txt = "C# Regular expression for combination of space, alpha and special-character. Also for delta";

var result = txt.replace(/[\w#]+\s*|[^\w#]+\s*/g, "<span>$&</span>\n");

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```